# administrative limit exceeded, REST

Tags: opendj

Using rest I got this exception

http://localhost:8080/customgroups?_queryFilter=(members/uid+co+%22test%22)

```
{"code":413,"reason":"Request Entity Too Large","message":"Administrative Limit Exceeded"}
```

I turned all limits off:

```
ds-cfg-lookthrough-limit: 0
ds-cfg-size-limit: 0
```

Is there another constrain? The result should be `1-3 entries`. Other requests like get all `customGroups = 83 or users = 1300` works fine, so why does the query_filter making problems?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you might try out:

- can you check the ds-rlim-lookthrough-limit operational attribute is correctly set? Especially for `cn=Directory Manager` if you are using it to make requests.
- I can see there is a special config for collective attributes `ds-rlim-lookthrough-limit;collective: 0`. Maybe does it apply to your request?

References:

- http://ludopoitou.com/2012/04/10/tips-resource-limits-in-opendj/
- http://opendj.forgerock.org/opendj-server/configref/global.html#lookthrough-limit
- http://docs.forgerock.org/en/opendj/2.6.0/admin-guide/index/chap-resource-limits.html